# Doubts about incoming parameters with karate

Tags: karate

I'm a beginner in karate and am currently trying to use karate to test the interface. The problem I'm currently having is that I can't pass the culsterId of the created cluster to the delete interface.

```
* table params
    | template        | path                          | name         | creator       | cdSize   | dcount     | dcpucount   | dmemory   | dcount   | dcpucount   | dcpumemory     |
    | 'createCluster' | '/zeppelin/api/sparkcluster'  | '0000'        | 'anonymous'   | 100      | 1          | 4           | 4         | 2        | 4           | 4              |
    | 'createCluster' | '/zeppelin/api/sparkcluster'  | '2222'        | 'anonymous'   | 20       | 1          | 4           | 1         | 1        | 1           | 2              |


    # call create interface
    * def createc_arg = call read('classpath:com/sequoiadb/featureTemplates/Create_Cluster.feature') params
    # get clusterId array
    * def clusterIds = $createc_arg[*].response.body.sparkClusterId
    # call delete interface
    * def result = call read('classpath:com/sequoiadb/featureTemplates/DeleteNewCluster.feature') clusterIds
```

Taking this code as an example, I can only pass createc_arg to the delete interface, not clusters (array format). why is that.

And even if you pass in createc_arg, you still get an array of clusterId in the end. How to pass in the path of the delete interface and delete all the clusterIds just created through the create interface.

These are my doubts and I am looking forward to your help.

Please accept my heartfelt thanks.

Comment: marked this as duplicate and you will get the answer in the linked question. if you still have doubts, ask another question, because combining multiple questions in one is not recommended